# Webservice Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, web-services, mxml

In my application I call a webservice. I try with the correct location of the WSDL and it works fine. When I change the WSDL location in the application (while running, not restarting the application) with and incorrect WSDL location, it still call the webservice with the correct location. Someone know why?

The webservice

```
<s:WebService id="MyWebService"
              wsdl="{modelLocator.webServiceAddress}"
              useProxy="false"/>
    <s:operation concurrency="multiple" name="GetFile" resultFormat="object"/>
</s:WebService>
```

How I change the location of the WSDL

```
<s:HGroup>
    <s:RadioButton label="WebService 1" groupName="radiogroup"
                   click="modelLocator.webServiceAddress = 'http://191.611.231.1/Service.asmx?WSDL'"/>
    <s:RadioButton label="WebService 2" groupName="radiogroup" selected="true"
                   click="modelLocator.webServiceAddress = 'http://192.168.0.5/Service.asmx?WSDL'"/>
</s:HGroup>
```

Before calling the operation of my webservice

```
var ws:WebService = ServiceLocator.getInstance().getWebService("MyWebService");
trace(ws.wsdl);
```

`trace(ws.wsdl)` give me the location od the WSDL that I select

Comment: How are you changing the WSDL location?.

Comment: is your modelLocator.webServiceAddress bindable?